# Azure Portal - How to delete bulk delete images?

Tags: azure, azure-image

In the Azure Portal, I'm in Home and then clicked on Images. From there, I checkboxed multiple images but there's no 'Delete' action that would allow me to delete multiple images at a time.  Is there any other way other than deleting one at a time?

[image]

Comment: I just look at azure portal. Home. I do not see images. Which means your description is not clear and assuming I know what is on your screen.

Comment: @new_to_azure FYI: the "Home" view is different for every user, and varies depending on which object types you use.

Answer (score 2):

For some reasons, there is no "delete" button in most views in the Azure Portal; however, there *is* a delete button in the "All resources" view.

Go to the "All resources" view, select the objects you want to delete and click the "Delete" button; you'll have to confirm the list by typing "yes".

You can search, filter and order the results, thus it should be easy to retrieve and select the objects you want to bulk delete.